# Does the Motorola Xoom have drawing bugs, or is it just me?

Tags: java, android

I've developed a little game and a friend/colleague of mine tried it on his Motorola Xoom tablet, only to find the rendering was all messed up! I stripped everything down trying to simplify everything to see what was wrong, and I'm thinking the Motorola Xoom is just buggy when it comes to drawing. The exact same APK was used on both, with the exact same drawing code. I've got a custom view that's just drawing a black rectangle right now, like so:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(16.0f, 16.0f);
    float lineWidth = 20 / 16.0f;

    paint.setAntiAlias(false);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(lineWidth);
    paint.setColor(boardColor); // boardColor is just black
    canvas.drawRect(100 / 16.0f,
                    100 / 16.0f,
                    200 / 16.0f,
                    200 / 16.0f,
                    paint);

    canvas.restore();
}
```

On my Sprint Galaxy SII, Android 4.0.4, I get (I also get this on a Galaxy SIII device):
[image: Galaxy SII screenshot]

On my friend's Motorola Xoom, Android 4.1.2, I get:
[image: Motorola Xoom screenshot]

All I want it is a correctly sized, non-antialiased rectangle. What am I doing wrong? Or is it the Xoom?

Comment: Another thing, haha, is that if you set antialiasing to true, the weird, faded square on the xoom is at least symmetrical. XD Though still blurry, which leads me to think that it indeed has something to do with that very small original line width size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It looks like this is indeed a bug in the Xoom (or perhaps it was Android), and has been fixed with Android 4.2](https://forums.motorola.com/posts/abe5b1e6b4?commentId=686537#686537).

Answer (score 0):

There is something weird going on with your scaling. If I take out the canvas.scale() and remove all the " / 16.0f"s in the rect, then the rect looks just fine. With those, I can confirm that my xoom shows the weird rectangle from your friend's xoom.

So, you'll need to figure out a different way to go about scaling the shape.

```
mPixelsInOneDp = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1,
            res.getDisplayMetrics());
```

I use that "mPixelsInOneDp to make sure all my measurements and what not end up being the same in DPs over different devices. I haven't had any problems with scaling, so I figure in the end you'll need to tweak your numbers until it looks fine on the xoom.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it on another Xoom. Do you have any idea as to why the Xoom fails at scaling graphics?

Comment: It actually doesn't.. I mean, I'm currently working on a project with lots of scaling and what not, without any problems. It might have something to do with the lower dp of the tablet compared to the higher one of the SII. Gonna edit that answer with something I use to scale graphics on devices..

Comment: Maybe since your lineWidth is ending up at 1.something pixels, scaling that 1-2 pixels is making it look weird. That's honestly all I can think of!

Comment: I don't think it's about the pixel density... There's no way the GS2 has 16x the pixel density of the Xoom, and my app was originally scaling by about 400x (making a 1x1 game board fill the window). What's weird is that if you set it to FILL instead of STROKE, it's fine...